# How to extend a Vuetify component and keep the ref?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently using a `v-textarea` like this:

```
# Main.vue
v-textarea(ref="myTextArea")
```

I would like to put a transparent wrapper around it so I can use the same customized version throughout my app. I'm doing this:

```
# CustomTextarea.vue
<template>
  <v-textarea v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"></v-textarea>
</template>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
# Main.vue
CustomTextarea(ref="myTextArea")
```

The problem is that now my `ref` no longer points to the actual `<textarea>` (it points to the custom component) so something like this no longer works:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.myTextarea.focus();
  });
}
```

I don't understand the magic that Vuetify is using, but it does work in `v-textarea`. Is there a way to do the same in my customized component?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I found my answer [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).

I just have to create the method and call it manually:

```
# CustomTextarea.vue
<template>
  <v-textarea 
    v-bind="$attrs" 
    v-on="$listeners"
    ref="input" //- <= add this
  ></v-textarea>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseTextarea',

  methods: {
    focus() {
      this.$refs.input.focus(); //- <= call it here
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I wonder if there is any way to automate this, but it works for now.